# reg: goldengate extract process not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

My extract process is not running, below is the errors found, kindly suggest how to get all process up and running.

```
GGSCI (pltv015) 3> info all

Program     Status      Group       Lag at Chkpt  Time Since Chkpt

MANAGER     RUNNING
EXTRACT     ABENDED     EXTEMP      00:00:04      05:46:53
EXTRACT     RUNNING     PUMPEMP     00:00:00      00:00:03
REPLICAT    STOPPED     REP507      00:00:00      00:18:08
REPLICAT    ABENDED     REPTEST     00:00:00      2527:29:44



 for EXTEMP :


2020-07-31 06:59:39 ERROR OGG-06601 Mismatch between the length of seqno from checkpoint (9) and recovery (6) for extract trail /opt/app/t1c2d507/ggs/t1c2d507/tr
ails/p1  

for  REP507 ::

2020-07-31 06:59:37 ERROR OGG-00664 OCI Error beginning session (status = 1017-ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied).

2020-07-31 06:59:37 ERROR OGG-01668 PROCESS ABENDING.


2020-07-31 06:59:39 ERROR OGG-06601 Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, extemp.prm: Mismatch between the length of seqno
 from checkpoint (9) and recovery (6) for extract trail /opt/app/t1c2d507/ggs/t1c2d507/trails/p1.
```

Comment: are you using Windows ??

Comment: no linux server

Comment: It matches a bug with `ERROR OGG-06601 Mismatch Between The Length Of Seqno From Checkpoint (9) And Recovery (6) For Ext `. I might provide you a guide workaround . Is your  Version 12.2.0.1.0 ?

Comment: 12.2.0.1.1   : Yes oracle version is 12.2.0.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it might help you. The following workaround applies only to Oracle GoldenGate version 12.2.0.1.0. Applies to any to any platform.

Running GG version 12.2 PUMP fails with this error

```
ERROR OGG-06601 Mismatch between the length of seqno from checkpoint (9) and recovery (6) for extract trail /path_to_the_trail/
```

Trying to read trail file which uses 6 digit checkpoint with version 12.2 when this version uses a 9 digit checkpoint. Same error might happen even when the trail files are actually having the same length as well. In that case, the error message is incorrect as it is related with a bug with code 25439681.

If the error "Mismatch between the length of seqno from checkpoint (9) and
recovery (6) for extract trail" is seen and the filename lengths are the same
then this bug may have been encountered. Note that this message masks the
real error message so the fix in Bug 25439681 does not resolve the underlying error but
makes sure the correct error is reported.

**Workaround**

**PART I**

- Stop PUMP
- Stop Manager
- Add the following to your GLOBALS file

  TRAIL_SEQLEN_6D

REASON: Tell GG to use 6 digit checkpoint

- Start Manager
- Alter Pump with ETROLLOVER
- Start Pump
- Allow PUMP to read local trail file and write them to a remote trail file
- Allow replicat to process all transactions. Replicat should show 0 lags to indicate all transactions , from the source, have been processed on the target database.

REASON: Clean up existing trail files, created from a prior release to GG version 12.2, still using a 6 digit checkpoint

**PART II**

Assuming you had no problems with PART I, then you need to perform some tasks both in source and target.

1. On Source

- Remove TRAIL_SEQLEN_6D from GLOBALS
- `alter ext E1 etrollover` where E1 is the name of your extract which creates the local trail file. REASON: ETROLLOVER needed to convert 6 digit checkpoint to 9 digits as well as GG version 12.2
- Use the following to display the new sequence number of local trail file.

  info extract E1, detail
  or
  info extract E1, showch
  Write Checkpoint #1
  Current Checkpoint (current write position):
  Sequence #: xx
  where xx = new sequence number of local trail file
- `alter ext P1, extseqno xx , extrba 0` (where xx = new sequence number of local trail file and P1 is the name of your PUMP) --> to handle input trail and the REASON: Tell PUMP to use the new local trail file created in step 1
- `alter ext p1, etrollover` ---> to handle output trail. Reason Tell PUMP to create and write to a new remote trail file.
- Use the following to display the new sequence number of the remote trail file

  info extract E1, detail
  or
  info extract E1, showch
  Write Checkpoint #1
  Current Checkpoint (current write position):
  Sequence #: yy
  where yy = new sequence number of the remote trail file

**On Target**

- `alter replicat R1, extseqno yy , extrba 0` where yy = new sequence number + 1 of the remote trail file

Go back to Source

- Allow changes to be made to Source tables involved with GG
- Perform insert or update to verify it gets replicated to the target.

**UPDATE**

To update the password of the CGADMIN

Step 1: check Golden Gate user

```
SQL> select username,account_status from dba_users where username like ‘GG%’;

USERNAME ACCOUNT_STATUS
—————————— ——————————–
GGADMIN OPEN
```

Step 2:  Change the password is database first

```
SQL> alter user GGADMIN identified by newpassWORD;
```

Step 3: Encrypt the new modified password in golden gate processes.

```
ENCRYPT PASSWORD passWORD ENCRYPTKEY DEFAULT

AACAAAAAAAAAAAIAWIVENGVBBFXEFEQH
```

Step 4: copy the password

```
dblogin userid GGADMIN, password AACAAAAAAAAAAAIAWIVENGVBBFXEFEQH, encryptkey default
```

Comment: Thanks experts, i checked the logs and found that password is changed for GG user today, I think due to that issue is coming, can you please update where need to update the new password...to bring all process up.

Comment: is after changing passwords in replicat and extract is i need to restart mgr process.